# How much money did Jerry's associates cost him over the series?

Tags: seinfeld

I've been re-watching Seinfeld since it became available on Netflix. One thing that really stands out to me on this viewing is how nearly every episode Jerry's friends, his family, or associates often cost him thousands of dollars.

Is there a definitive list or summary of all the costs Jerry incurred from his friends, family, and associations?

Examples:

- Kramer costs Jerry $1500 when he ruins the washing machines.
- George costs Jerry thousands of dollars when he wrecks his rental car.
- Elaine's father cost him some unspecified amount when he insists that he wear his suede jacket right-side out in the snow.

Comment: I don't think you can calculate his money lost, he lost other valuable things as reputation, morals, sanity and freedom (got arrested), but gained access to their *dementia*

Comment: Why is this off-topic?

Comment: I didn't marked it off topic, but are you asking to calculate costs of jerry in all the series ? is that your question?